# Let $g_{ij}$ be a Riemannian metric in normal coordinates at $p$. Why is $\partial_k g_{ij}(p)=0$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, fix a point $p\in M$, let $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ be an orthonormal basis for $\mathrm{T}_p M$, let $$\exp_p:\mathrm{B}_{\mathrm{T}_p M}(0,\varepsilon)\to\mathrm{B}_M(p,\varepsilon)$$ be a diffeomorphism defining a normal neighborhood, and use the coordinates $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ on $\mathrm{B}_{\mathrm{T}_p M}(0,\varepsilon)$ to induce coordinates $x^1,\ldots,x^n$ on $M$. Then we have the following properties:

- $p = (0,\ldots,0)$ in coordinates
- Geodesics starting at $(0,\ldots,0)$ are of the form $\gamma(t) = t\,v$ for some $v\in\mathrm{T}_p M$
- $g_{ij}(0,\ldots,0) = \delta_{ij}$

I know how to prove these three properties, but I don't see how to easily compute $g_{ij}$ in all of $\mathrm{B}_{\mathrm{T}_p M}(0,\varepsilon)$. How would I show that $\partial_k g_{ij}=0$?

Comment: What is $\partial_k \langle e_i, e_j \rangle$?

Comment: Is that a question or a hint?

Comment: A hint. The brackets denote the scalar product given by the metric.

Comment: Well, $\partial_k\langle\partial_i,\partial_j\rangle = \langle\nabla_{\partial_k}\partial_i,\partial_j\rangle + \langle\partial_i,\nabla_{\partial_k}\partial_j\rangle$.

Comment: I can see that $\nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_i=0$ just by using geodesic arguments, but I don't see why we must have that $\langle\nabla_{\partial_k}\partial_i,\partial_j\rangle=0$, say.

Comment: It is not zero. Since you like using coordinate bases, then what does it mean that the connection is metric, in such a basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\gamma (t)=\exp_p\ te_i$ and $E_k$ is normal coordinate vector
field, then $ E_k(t)=(d\exp_p)_{te_i}\ e_k$, and $ (\gamma
'(t),E_k(t))=0$ by Gauss lemma

Hence $$0=\gamma'(\gamma',E_k)=(E_i,\nabla_{E_i} E_k) $$

Hence $$ 0=(E_j+E_k,\nabla_{E_j+E_k} E_m)
=(E_j,\nabla_{E_k}E_m)+(E_k,\nabla_{E_j}E_m) = E_m (E_k,E_j)$$